# Jasper Reports cutting large String between pages

Tags: java, string

I don't know if "cutting" is the right term...

I've got to finish doing a large and complex report based on an Applet legacy system, a fellow and I decided trying reuse all the logic in the applet to avoid the complexity of doing a lot of sub-reports. What we did was copy all the logic in the applet that include a lot of condictionals/SQL and make a huge and properly formated String, so that in our Jasper file it would just have a method called "myVo.getBody()" besides the header and footer stuff.

Unfortunately we found out a problem that some part of text get lost between pages. I think that  as the text get bigger and reach Jasper page limit for some reason it keeps being writed in a "no visible area" and when the next page content starts some part was lost.

For example, there is a list of 19 items and what happens is:

End of 2nd page
1 - item
2 - item
beggining of 3rd page
18th - item
19th - item

Items from 3 to 17 are not being showed.

Is there any Jasper configuration for this situation?

We tried:
Position type: Fix Relative to the Top and Float
Stretch Type: Relative to the Tallers Object and Relative to Band Height
Stretch With Overflot: true or false

I don't think showing Java code would be useful as it just use a StringBuffer to build the String, put it on body property in a PreparedDocumentVO so that Jasper model can consumes it. It seems to be some Jasper setting, or the idea of creating a huge String is not so good as we thought.

Comment: You've been using the site for three years now, how about setting your user name to something a bit more personal.  Something that reflects you, or what you care about, instead of just the randomly generated id?

Comment: Ok I can do It....when I started using I have the thought "it is just a question", there is no need to such a personal thing, but time has passed and I still here.

Comment: I get that, but we like talking to people more than we like talking to numbers, and you're probably happier being a bit more than "just a number" too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider breaking the result up.

Jasper formats information based on a relative page size.  This means that at some point in time, when dealing with information that is not likely to fit on a page, Jasper will probably make an assumption that doesn't hold (and your data will likely not be formatted into the page).

If you have an exceptionally long string, consider splitting it up.  Besides, people scroll web pages down, not the side, so a heavy side-scrolling document is likely to cause user issues unless every record scrolls to the side just as heavily.

Comment: Finally we got what was wrong.

There some "\t" in the lines missing, as we replaced with some ordinary spaces solved the problem.